# PHP str_replace weird results

Tags: php, arrays, gd, str-replace, explode

i have these codes:

```
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");

$first = array("Captain","Dirty","Squidlips","Bowman","Buccaneer","Two Toes","Sharkbait","Old","Peg Leg","Fluffbucket","Scallywag","Bucko","Dead man","Matey","Jolly","Stinky","Bloody","Miss","Mad","Red","Lady","Bretheren","Rapscallion","Landlubber","Wench","Freebooter");

ImageTTFText($image, 45, 0, 0, $y-intval("30"), imageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255), "pirate-font.ttf", str_replace($alphabet,$first,"bad"));
```

Please help me fix this weird problem...
i think there is something wrong they i coded it, but i don't know which is which...

With the code above...

supposedly, the output must be `Dirty Captain Bowman`
but it's odd that it outputs the wrong result...

check this: http://alylores.x10.mx/106/pic.php

Please help me fix my problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left to right functionality of `str_replace` causes this, unfortunately.  So here is an alternative.

Here is an example of the code below: [Example.](http://codepad.org/MTypZkMj)

```
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");

$first = array("Captain","Dirty","Squidlips","Bowman","Buccaneer","Two Toes","Sharkbait","Old","Peg Leg","Fluffbucket","Scallywag","Bucko","Dead man","Matey","Jolly","Stinky","Bloody","Miss","Mad","Red","Lady","Bretheren","Rapscallion","Landlubber","Wench","Freebooter");

// split bad into an array, each letter being its own value.
$input = str_split('bad');

// Alphabet become the keys, $first are the values
$c = array_combine($alphabet, $first);

$output = '';
foreach ($input as $letter)
{
    $output .= $c[$letter] . ' ';
}

$final_word = trim($output);

ImageTTFText($image, 45, 0, 0, $y-intval("30"), imageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255), "pirate-font.ttf", $final_word);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);

// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

// Outputs: apearpearle pear
// For the same reason mentioned above
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Pseudo Code:

1. Split String to Array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php Split Length = 1)
2. replace each value in every arrayentry
3. put the string together again.

Comment: Also there is a [large "Caution" block in the documentation regarding this](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-notes).

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag It's not a solution, just an explanation. It's pasted from the php.net site.

Comment: yeah i not its an explanation sir... what i need is a solution... coz i dont know how to modify this....

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag I've already written it for you.. scroll down.